# IObitUninstaller : is it POSSIBLE to uninstall it?

Tags: windows-11, uninstall

Yesterday I installed IObitUninstaller.exe on my Windows 11 Home laptop.
It always decides to install several other programs I do not want, such as iTopVPN.exe, IObitDownloader.exe, and  and iScrRec.exe too.
I used the program and immediately uninstalled it, and uninstalled all the files I was able to locate that installed themselves, but no matter how much time I spent doing all of these things, I still have IObitDowloader.exe, iTopVPN.exe, and iScrRec.exe showing in my Taskbar's corner overflow. Plus, instead of GAINING extra room on my C drive, I've lost over 3GB after all the items I used the UNINSTALLER program to help me to get rid of.
I need to get rid of all these hidden files and just don't know where to begin.
Okay, to clarify... I'm seeking a tool that will remove icons from my Taskbar corner overflow once I've uninstalled the programs from my laptop. I'm using Windows 11 Home version 21H2.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See if Revo Uninstaller can install the whole lot. iOBit is not malicious, but by ye goddes it is insidious. Once clean, stop using 'make my PC better' software.

Comment: Also, don't forget to reboot after the uninstall. Sometimes it just needs a reboot to finish the uninstall because files were in use.

Comment: Have you tried to simply uninstall those programs from the Add/Remove function built-into Windows, all of those applications you listed, I would expect to have installed by their own installer even if they were ran silently by another installer.